# How To Implement Binary Subtraction Using Emulated Logic Gates in Python?

Tags: python

I am in the process of creating a CPU simulator using Python. This project is not intended to be extremely accurate. Instead, it is meant to show the basic logic of a CPU, cache, RAM, ALU, etc.

I am struggling to implement a binary subtraction function using logic gates. Below is what I have so far:

These are the logic gates:

```
class ANDGate:
    def execute(a, b):
        result = ""
        for bit_a, bit_b in zip(a, b):
            result += '1' if bit_a == '1' and bit_b == '1' else '0'
        return result


class ORGate:
    def execute(a, b):
        result = ""
        for bit_a, bit_b in zip(a, b):
            result += '1' if bit_a == '1' or bit_b == '1' else '0'
        return result


class XORGate:
    def execute(a, b):
        result = ""
        for bit_a, bit_b in zip(a, b):
            result += '1' if (bit_a == '1' and bit_b == '0') or (bit_a == '0' and bit_b == '1') else '0'
        return result


class NOTGate:
    def execute(a):
        result = ""
        for bit_a in a:
            result += '0' if bit_a == '1' else '1'
        return result
```

And this is the subtraction method:

```
def subtract(a, b):
        result = ""
        borrow = '0'
        max_len = max(len(a), len(b))

        # Zero-pad the shorter operand
        a = a.zfill(max_len)
        b = b.zfill(max_len)

        for bit_a, bit_b in zip(reversed(a), reversed(b)):
            diff = XORGate.execute(XORGate.execute(bit_a, bit_b), borrow)
            borrow = ORGate.execute(ANDGate.execute(NOTGate.execute(bit_a), bit_b),
                                    ANDGate.execute(XORGate.execute(bit_a, bit_b), borrow))
            result = diff + result
            print(f"bit_a: {bit_a}, bit_b: {bit_b}, diff: {diff}, borrow: {borrow}, result: {result}")

        # Handle the most significant bit
        result = XORGate.execute(result[0], borrow) + result[1:]

        # Trim leading zeros
        result = result.lstrip('0') or '0'

        return result
```

With the input 101010 and 1100, the result should be 11110. However, the current output is 101110. Below is the printed debug statement from the method:

```
bit_a: 0, bit_b: 0, diff: 0, borrow: 0, result: 0
bit_a: 1, bit_b: 0, diff: 1, borrow: 0, result: 10
bit_a: 0, bit_b: 1, diff: 1, borrow: 1, result: 110
bit_a: 1, bit_b: 1, diff: 1, borrow: 0, result: 1110
bit_a: 0, bit_b: 0, diff: 0, borrow: 0, result: 01110
bit_a: 1, bit_b: 0, diff: 1, borrow: 0, result: 101110
bit_a: 0, bit_b: 0, diff: 0, borrow: 0, result: 0
bit_a: 1, bit_b: 0, diff: 1, borrow: 0, result: 10
bit_a: 0, bit_b: 1, diff: 1, borrow: 1, result: 110
bit_a: 1, bit_b: 1, diff: 1, borrow: 0, result: 1110
bit_a: 0, bit_b: 0, diff: 0, borrow: 0, result: 01110
bit_a: 1, bit_b: 0, diff: 1, borrow: 0, result: 101110
```

How can I adjust this method to perform binary subtraction accurately using the logic gates? Thanks in advance.

Comment: a style note, having classes with only a single static method (without the staticmethod decorator...) "execute", should almost certainly just be functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have tweaked the code a little

```
def subtract(a, b):
    result = ""
    borrow = '0'
    max_len = max(len(a), len(b))

    # Zero-pad the shorter operand
    a = a.zfill(max_len)
    b = b.zfill(max_len)

    for bit_a, bit_b in zip(reversed(a), reversed(b)):
        
        diff = XORGate.execute(XORGate.execute(bit_a, bit_b), borrow)
        borrow= ORGate.execute(ORGate.execute(ANDGate.execute(NOTGate.execute(bit_a), bit_b),
                                                   ANDGate.execute(NOTGate.execute(bit_a), borrow)),
                                    ANDGate.execute(bit_b, borrow))
        result = diff + result

    # Trim leading zeros
    result = result.lstrip('0') or '0'

    return result
```

You should get the desired output

Comment: Please *explain what you did* and *why*.

Comment: This is done using the concept of Full Subtractor using logic gates. And it can be easily looked up on internet and to combine it all and bring together, we need an additional or there.

Comment: Also removed the xor in the end which in turn is eeplaced by the above or

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a use of the not gate for calculating the borrow. Otherwise, `1 - 0` with borrow `1` would result in `borrow = 1` for the next iteration.

```py
borrow = ORGate.execute(ANDGate.execute(NOTGate.execute(bit_a), bit_b),
                        ANDGate.execute(NOTGate.execute(XORGate.execute(bit_a, bit_b)), borrow))
```